# Is it possible to make POST request in Flask?

Tags: python, post, flask

There is a need to make POST request from server side in Flask.

Let's imagine that we have:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    test = request.form["test"]
    return "TEST: %s" % test

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    # Is there something_like_this method in Flask to perform the POST request?
    return something_like_this("/test", { "test" : "My Test Data" })
```

I haven't found anything specific in Flask documentation. Some say `urllib2.urlopen` is the issue but I failed to combine Flask and `urlopen`. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, to make a POST request you can use `urllib`, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

I would however recommend to use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) module instead.

**EDIT**:

I suggest you refactor your code to extract the common functionality:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    return _test(request.form["test"])

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return _test("My Test Data")

def _test(argument):
    return "TEST: %s" % argument
```

Comment: Hmmm, yeah. That would actually involve making a network request, for little reason. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to make a "request" to your own application, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Refactoring to extract functionality is good advice, and gets around the problem while making the code more flexible +1

Comment: A note on _why_ to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request) module will help

Comment: minus 1: link is broken and includes no details on *how* to make post request.

Answer (score 81):

For the record, here's general code to make a POST request from Python:

```
#make a POST request
import requests
dictToSend = {'question':'what is the answer?'}
res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/tests/endpoint', json=dictToSend)
print 'response from server:',res.text
dictFromServer = res.json()
```

Notice that we are passing in a Python dict using the `json=` option. This conveniently tells the requests library to do two things:

1. serialize the dict to JSON
2. write the correct MIME type ('application/json') in the HTTP header

And here's a Flask application that will receive and respond to that POST request:

```
#handle a POST request
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/tests/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def my_test_endpoint():
    input_json = request.get_json(force=True) 
    # force=True, above, is necessary if another developer 
    # forgot to set the MIME type to 'application/json'
    print 'data from client:', input_json
    dictToReturn = {'answer':42}
    return jsonify(dictToReturn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'd like to comment how important is the `json=` part mentioned in @Luke's answer. I was struggling with this one for hours. Found the answer here.