# How can I redirect without revealing URI fields in flask?

Tags: python, redirect, post, flask

I would like to make a post request sending a username and password to a page named showInternal; I currently accomplish this via:

```
username = "johnsmith"
password = "password1234"
return redirect(url_for('showInternal', username=username, password=password))
```

for the redirect and

```
@app.route('/internal', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def showInternal():
    return render_template('internal.html')
```

for the destination page.  This sorta works in the sense that it takes me to `/internal?password=password1234&username=johnsmith`.

However, I don't want to show the user's username and password in the url.  I've tried replacing the phrase `methods=['GET']` with  `methods=['POST']` but then I get an error about that method not being allowed, and the data stays in the url anyhow.

How can I pass these data without it showing up in the url?

Comment: You can't redirect to a POST, so the way I would do it is via a session.

Comment: Wait, of course you can redirect with a post - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15473626/3238611

Comment: I thought you were trying to redirect a GET to a POST, misread.  I don't believe a GET to a POST is honored by any clients and don't know how that would be done unless the original request included a body.

Comment: I need one view to make sure the username/password are good, and I need them in the other because flask's @login_required needs a request object with the fields.  For that reason, I also can't just call the function unless they're some way to do so while including a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the JSON and requests module: 
`import json, request`

Use the request module to send a post request:

```
requests.post('<full-url>', data=json.dumps({'username': 'johnsmith', 'password': 'password1234'}))
```

Then edit your route:

```
@app.route('/internal', methods=['POST'])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - when I try it, it hangs up on the call to requests.post without actually reaching the page.

Comment: I just edited the answer, try that one out, there was a typo

Comment: I don't think that's the problem - requests *is* the name of the module.

Comment: Sorry, same problem as originally - it hangs up on the call to reqests.post

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313001/is-it-possible-to-make-post-request-in-flask