# Is it possible to add arguments to a request using POST method?

Tags: python, redirect, post, flask, request

I'm building a Flask web application. Now I'm trying to make a form with the POST method, get the input values, use it and pass an error code to the view function of the form's template. The error code is a simple integer to know if any error occurred. With that, I want to redirect the user where they belong: the form's template.

So far, I send the form's request to some routed URL that I call here `append_request`. From this URL, I call a function `append_request()` that will get the input values within the `request.form` dictionary. Lastly, I redirect the user by saving their last URL as an argument of the request: `url_source`.

How can I pass an error code to the view function `view_template()` ? I was thinking about appending somehow the request with an argument. But I can't see how, since i can't modify the `request.form` dictionary because it's [immutable](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.form) .

Here is what my form looks like in `template.html` at `url_template`:

```html
<form method="POST" action="append_request">
    <input hidden name="url_source" value="{{ request.path }}">  <!-- save current url -->
    <input name="arg">
    <!-- some other input omited -->
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the Flask part:

```py
@app.route('append_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def append_request():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url_source = request.form.get('url_source', None)
        arg = request.form.get('arg', None)
        # some other arguments omited ...
        # some processing with arguments ... 

        # The error code i get after processing
        # I want to pass it to view_template()
        error_code = 1234    

    if url_source:
        return redirect(url_source, code=307)    # code 307 preserve the POST method
    else:
        return abort(400)    # raise HTTP error if no redirection possible


@app.route('url_template')
def view_template()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('error_code:',error_code)          # i want to access to error code here!
    return render_template('template.html')
```

I know I could [recreate a whole request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313001/is-it-possible-to-make-post-request-in-flask), but I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Have you considered / are you using `flask-wtforms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. After few days, I ended up by remaking the whole functions!

I think there is a design mistake in my method. I don't think adding arguments to a POST request is possible. I even don't think it's necessary. I just wanted to display an error message on the page and I ended up by simply use the [flash](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.flash) function  documented in the Flask Tutorial about [message flashing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing).