# Flask-Login login to a service using POST request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-login

I'm trying to build a flask webapp that connects the user to a service that requires the user to login but I'm having trouble relaying the login.

The service's authentication works (quite unusual) the following way:

- You authenticate with *userid*, *loginname* and *password*
- This returns JSON with a *token*
- After you have authenticated you can get data by providing your *userid* and the recieved *token*

This is my User Class:

```py
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid
        self.token = None


    def get_id(self):
        return self.userid


    def login(self, loginname, password):
        # Request
        data = {'userid' : self.userid, 'loginname' : loginname, 'password' : password}
        r = requests.post('https://myurl.com/authenticate', data=data)
        
        # If Failure
        if r.status_code != 200:
            flash('Unsuccessful Login!', 'danger')
            return False

        # Extracting the Token
        self.token = r.json()['token']

        # Success
        flash('You have successfully logged in!', 'success')
        return True
```

And this is the routing of the login page, which uses a WTForm which is defined below.

```py
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(form.userid.data)
        if user.login(form.loginname.data, form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

```py
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    userid = StringField('User ID', validators=[DataRequired()])
    loginname = StringField('Loginname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

I believe I must use a `request_loader` but both the authorization headers and the args are empty when the login button is clicked.

```py
@login_manager.request_loader
def load_user_from_request(request):
    print('AUTH', request.headers.get('Authorization')) # -> None
    print('ARGS', request.args) # -> ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

How is `request_loader` supposed to access *userid*, *loginname* and *password* in this scenario?

Comment: Use the [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests "Note that this is the github page.") module to easily get/post requests.
___
This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313001/is-it-possible-to-make-post-request-in-flask)

Comment: @awesomesauce I do actually use the `requests.post` method in the code posted. I'm having trouble combining the request with flask-login as I want that service to take full control over authorizing users.